# Python Script that calls the Voronoi Polygons Function?

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, python-2.7, voronoi-thiessen

I've been looking to see if there was a way to call Voronoi Polygons function found in Vector/Geometry Tools, directly from the code but I have not found one. Does this currently exist? Is there a way to call these functions within python coding?

Comment: this code may help you https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/plugins/fTools/tools/voronoi.py

Comment: Hmm, the code does offer some insight. However, what needs to be imported so the in-built functions like computeVoronoiDiagram() can be used?

Comment: sorry i have never used this script, i've found it just by googling for you.

Comment: Oh alright, thanks for the help. I'll tinker with it see if there is a way to make it work.

Comment: cant you use the processing tool? i.e. grass:v.voronoi and qgis:voronoipolygons

Answer (score 2):

BJEBN has suggested a function from the processing toolbox. Here's how to use it: As per http://qgis.org/de/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

From the console you can get a list of all the algorithms available which contain the word "Voronoi" by typing:

```
import processing
processing.alglist("Voronoi")
```

Then you could find out how to use what appears the most appropriate function with:

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:voronoipolygons")
```

Then simply use the algorithm in your script as follows:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:voronoipolygons",inputlayer,"output_file.shp")
```